# Defining Window for Testing in Mocha

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, zombie.js

I'm trying to integrate some testing into my current Backbone/CoffeeScript application.

I have created a module for my application baked into the window object, but running any mocha tests fail because window is undefined.

```
 module = (name) ->
   window[name] = window[name] or {}
 module 'Cart'
```

Any direction as to how I can define window for mocha?

I did try using jsdom and creating a window that way, but it still threw the same error. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Using zombie.js is getting me further then using jsdom.

```
zombie = require 'zombie'
browser = new zombie.Browser
browser.window.location = 'http://local.cart'
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to access the DOMWindow and set a variable to one of its values.

It would be ideal if browser.window was the same object as returned from accessing window in Chrome console, but it isn't.

I can access what I'm looking for with

```
zombie.visit 'http://local.cart', (err, browser) ->
  throw err if err
  browser.window.Cart
```

Is there a way for me to set what this returns to a global variable I can use throughout all of my specs?

Can't seem to get what I want trying a beforeEach or setting the previous block to a method and setting a variable to that method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll definitely want to mock window, as opposed to trying to pass around a real DOM window object in the node side of your app (mocha).

Try this pattern I just whipped up (sort of conforms to mocha tutorials I have read and uses the `this` context which changes when in browser (window) vs. run on node (exports):

```
/**
 * My namespace is 'AV'
 */
(function(root) {
    /**
     * @namespace root namespace object
     */
    root['AV'] = root['AV'] || {};
    var AV = root['AV'];

    AV.CoolThing = {
        //...
    };

    // this will give you
    // your "window" object
    // which is actually
    // module.exports
    return root;

})(this);
```

Then, the test might look something like this (mine are in coffeescript too):

```
chai = require 'chai'
chai.should()

# exports / "window"
{ AV } = require '../src/AV.js'

describe 'Sample test with namespace', ->
    it 'should be an object', ->
        AV.should.be.an 'object'
```