# MochaJS 'Window Is Undefined'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, window, mocha.js

In MochaJS, I keep receiving this error when importing my JS file for testing:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

My js file is written with the following pattern, which I believe is best practice for defining window level variables:

```
if (typeof window.myVar === 'undefined') {
  window.myVar = ...
}
```

According to:
[What is the correct way to check if a global variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596315/what-is-the-standard-way-to-check-if-a-global-variable-exists)

At any rate, it seems reasonable that one should be able to make a reference to 'window' at any point within a js file without breaking a unit test.

I do NOT want to simulate going to a URL (as zombieJS tutorials seems to assume), nor can I get zombieJS or phantomJS to create a mock of the window object.

Inserting

```
var window = {};
```

Into my unit test has no effect.

Other posts that seem to deal with this, such as [Defining Window for Testing in Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091025/defining-window-for-testing-in-mocha) make absolutely no sense to me.

How do people deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

Basically it involves passing whatever the root object is as "this" to the function that is being unit tested.

I wrote a more [comprehensive blog post](http://freepender.blogspot.com/2013/10/javascript-unit-testing-with-mocha.html) on it.